# Image segmentation (OCT)

Tags: image-segmentation

My image is something like below:

[image]

I want to be able to draw 2 layers: (1) red line on **top** of 1st layer, but (2) blue line in the **middle** of 2nd layer

I am using OpenCV. but any languages/advice are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. Small closing in order to reconnect the small separated components/patterns.
2. Small opening in order to remove the small isolated components/patterns.
3. Skeletonize (or median axis)
4. Pruning in order to remove the small branches.

You will then get a skeleton for each pattern. It will be close to the lines you want to draw. But it will be a little bit irregular, so you can interpolate it.

[EDIT] if you need the red line on top of the edge, a solution is to:

1. Extract the pattern contour
2. Keep only the pixel on top.

Algorithmically, it can be achieved doing this: for each X coordinate on the top border, go down the image vertically until you meet the first non-null pixel. If your image is NxM, you must have N pixels in your solution.

If you want to regularize/smooth the result, you have two solutions:

1. Transform the contour as a parametric function and smooth it.
2. Do an interpolation (spline?)

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply. I followed step 1 and 2 and it seems to work really well to move unwanted parts. But how can I possibly get the red line in the first layer of my image? I need the red line to be the 'top edge' of the layer.

Comment: 'Keep only the pixel on top'...                How can I achieve this, because pixels of the contours on the bottomleft might be even 'higher' than the pixels on the topright on the contour.

Comment: I've edited my answer. You start from the image top, and you go down.